# RSA encryption/decryption values not working as expected

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, decryption

I'm faced with an issue I can't seem to understand when it comes to RSA. Below are my values for all of the parameters, unfortunately I can't seem to get the expected decrypted values from my encryption message

```
p=113, q=117,phi=12992,n=13221
encryptionKey = e = 8473
decryptionKey = d = e^-1 = 12969
msg = 3;
(encryption) cipher = (3)^(8473) (mod 13221) = 6633
(decryption) msg = (6633)^(12969) (mod 13221) = 12546
```

**why is the msg prior to encryption not equal to msg after encryption? how to get them equal ?**

Comment: linux command `factor 117 : 3 3 13`. Also $1+1+7 = 9 $ this mean that $3|117$

Comment: sorry I don't get why that is an issue ? sorry i have some gaps in my knowledge

Comment: your $q$ is not a prime!

Comment: hey yeah you were right this was my problem... sorry what a silly mistake on my part !!! do you want to post this as an official answer ?